# Why am I getting a NoSuchBucket 404 error when forwarding www?

Tags: http, amazon-s3, forwarding

I'm trying to forward (with masking) www.theaxelrods.com to my Amazon S3 hosted static site at http://axelrods.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com.

For some reason theaxelrods.com forwards just fine, but www.theaxelrods.com does not.  I even tried adding www as a subdomain and forwarding from there.

What could be causing this error?

> 404 Not Found
>
> ```
> Code: NoSuchBucket
> Message: The specified bucket does not exist
> BucketName: www.theaxelrods.com
> RequestId: 13C929CE3C10699B
> HostId: fmi7K3bgEjRFxah/hxzyGx1FKy1Pte3+BK6TrNWcgy9KwsabLODfXZmGagnWkz3J
> ```

Comment: did you make any changes to "ServerAlias"  inside site-enabled of apcahe

Comment: http://improve.dk/how-to-set-up-and-serve-private-content-using-s3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Bucketname` are a global namespace on Amazon S3 and must be unique. Read more about this [here](http://support.rightscale.com/09-Clouds/AWS/FAQs/FAQ_0094_-_What_are_valid_S3_bucket_names%3F).

So, you can create another `Bucketname` with `www.theaxelrods.com`, if you want to use it with `www.*`

I don`t try/needed it before... but I found this [article](http://pixelcog.com/blog/2013/routing-with-s3/), for routing with Route53.

Comment: The article wasn't terribly helpful, as Amazon is not my domain host (I'm using godaddy.)  However, to keep things simple, I just created a subdomain redirect from www to theaxelrods.com, which then forwards to a single S3 bucket.